# e'ing a matrix and then finding eigenvalues and a ivp to converge to the origion

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The question is as follow's consider the Matrix A

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 &0\\ 1 & \lambda&0 \\ 0&1& \lambda  \end{pmatrix},$$

Compute $e^{tA}$, and use it to solver the initial value problem

$X^{'}$ = AX,

$X(0)$=$X_{0}$=$(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$

Question (ii)

Under what conditions on $\lambda$ and $X_{0}$ does the solution $X(t)$ of the initial value problem converges to the origin as t tends to $\infty$ Justify.

For part 1 i know what it says, it wants me to write $e^{tA}$ where A is actually my matrix i was sick for class and the notes i have are barely legible and as per usual my textbook doesn't have any worked out example's only a proof.

So if someone could show me how to set this up and/or point me in the direction of some dummy level examples with a nice explanation i would appreciate that.

For part 2 i think id like to construct a stable star node but any value where all the eigenvalues $\lambda <0$ should converge to (0,0,0) in infinite time ?

also why does the IVP matter in this case everything should move to (0,0,0) in eithier finite or infinite time if all the eigenvalues are negative?

Comment: To compute the powers of $A$, it may help to write $A=\lambda I_3 +N$ where $N$ is nilpotent and commutes, of course, with $\lambda I_3$. Once you have that, you'll get $\exp (tA)$.

Comment: Whats nilpotent mean?

Comment: $M$ is nilpotent $\Leftrightarrow \exists k\in\mathbb{N}, M^k=0_n$

Comment: It makes it really easy to calculate the exponential because you have a finite number of terms to add since $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}\cfrac{M^k}{k!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\cfrac{M^k}{k!}+\sum\limits_{k=n}^{+\infty}\cfrac{M^k}{k!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\cfrac{M^k}{k!}+\sum\limits_{k=n}^{+\infty}\cfrac{0_n}{k!}$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\cfrac{M^k}{k!}$

Comment: ah, ic and $0_{n}$ is the 0 matrix where n is the number of times we multiply it by itself to get the 0 matrix.

Comment: No >_< $0_n$ is the zero of $M_n(\mathbb{K})$. $0_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $0_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $0_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Since $M^k=0^n$, $\forall p \in\mathbb{N}, M^{k+p}=M^kM^p=0_nM^p=0_n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 &0\\ 1 & \lambda&0 \\ 0&1& \lambda  \end{pmatrix} =  \lambda\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &0\\ 0 & 1&0 \\ 0&0& 1  \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 1 & 0&0 \\ 0&1& 0  \end{pmatrix} = \lambda I_3 + N$

$e^A = e^{\lambda I_3 + N}$

Since the two matrices commute, ie $(\lambda I_3) N = N(\lambda I_3)$

$e^A = e^{\lambda I_3}e^{N}$

$e^{\lambda I_3}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\cfrac{\left(\lambda I_3\right)^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\cfrac{\lambda^n  I_3^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\cfrac{\lambda^n  I_3}{n!}=\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\cfrac{\lambda^n  }{n!}\right)I_3 = e^\lambda I_3$

$N^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 1 & 0&0 \\ 0&1& 0  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 1 & 0&0 \\ 0&1& 0  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 0 & 0&0 \\ 1&0& 0  \end{pmatrix}$

$N^3=N N^2 =\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 1 & 0&0 \\ 0&1& 0  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 0 & 0&0 \\ 1&0& 0  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 0 & 0&0 \\ 0&0& 0  \end{pmatrix} = 0_3$

$e^N = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\cfrac{\left(\lambda N\right)^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2}\cfrac{\left(\lambda N\right)^n}{n!}+\sum\limits_{n=3}^{+\infty}\cfrac{\left(\lambda N\right)^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2}\cfrac{\left(\lambda N\right)^n}{n!} = \cfrac{I_3}{0!}+\cfrac{N}{1!}+\cfrac{N^2}{2!}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &0\\ 0 & 1&0 \\ 0&0& 1  \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 1 & 0&0 \\ 0&1& 0  \end{pmatrix}+\cfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 &0\\ 0 & 0&0 \\ 1&0& 0  \end{pmatrix}=\cfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 &0\\ 2 & 2&0 \\ 1&2& 2  \end{pmatrix}$

$e^A = e^{\lambda I_3}e^{N}=\cfrac{e^{\lambda}}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 &0\\ 2 & 2&0 \\ 1&2& 2  \end{pmatrix}$

---

$e^{tA}=e^{t\lambda I_3 + tN}=e^{t\lambda I_3}e^{tN}=\cfrac{e^{\lambda t}}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 &0\\ 2t & 2&0 \\ t^2&2t& 2  \end{pmatrix}$

$X(0)=X_0=\begin{pmatrix} x_0\\ y_0 \\ z_0  \end{pmatrix}$

$X'=AX\tag{E}$

The unique solution is $X(t)=e^{tA}X_0=\cfrac{e^{\lambda t}}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 &0\\ 2t & 2&0 \\ t^2&2t& 2  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_0\\ y_0 \\ z_0  \end{pmatrix}=\cfrac{e^{\lambda t}}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 2x_0\\ 2tx_0+2y_0 \\ t^2 x_0 + 2t y_0 + 2z_0  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} e^{\lambda t}x_0\\ e^{\lambda t}\left(tx_0+y_0\right) \\ e^{\lambda t}\left(\cfrac{t^2}{2} x_0 + t y_0 + z_0\right)  \end{pmatrix}$

---

We want $\begin{pmatrix} e^{\lambda t}x_0\\ e^{\lambda t}\left(tx_0+y_0\right) \\ e^{\lambda t}\left(\cfrac{t^2}{2} x_0 + t y_0 + z_0\right)  \end{pmatrix}\underset{t\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Since the space is finite dimensional ($3 < +\infty$), convergence is the same thing as convergence coordinate wise.

So $\begin{pmatrix} e^{\lambda t}x_0\\ e^{\lambda t}\left(tx_0+y_0\right) \\ e^{\lambda t}\left(\cfrac{t^2}{2} x_0 + t y_0 + z_0\right)  \end{pmatrix}\underset{t\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\Leftrightarrow \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        e^{\lambda t}x_0 \underset{t\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 \\
        e^{\lambda t}\left(tx_0+y_0\right)\underset{t\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\\
        e^{\lambda t}\left(\cfrac{t^2}{2} x_0 + t y_0 + z_0\right)\underset{t\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0
    \end{array}
\right.\Leftrightarrow \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \lambda < 0 \mbox{ or } x_0 = 0\\
        \lambda < 0 \mbox{ or } x_0=y_0 = 0\\
        \lambda < 0 \mbox{ or } x_0=y_0=z_0 = 0
    \end{array}
\right.\Leftrightarrow \lambda < 0 \mbox{ or } x_0=y_0=z_0 = 0$

Comment: Wow  that's extremely straight forward...

Comment: Well usually the tricky part is to decompose the matrix into a diagonal matrix (because you know that $e^{diag(a_1,\dots,a_n)}=diag(e^{a_1},\dots,e^{a_n})$) and a nilpotent matrix (because then you only have a finite number of terms to add). And in your case, the matrix was made to make this decomposition easy to find.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: That doesn't surprise me the textbook talks about this idea for about, 3 pages. any hints for the IVP n why i can't just pick anything?

Comment: @Faust7: I edited.

Comment: I dont really understand it all but i get pieces of it, thank you for all the work though. i can read the bottom part but im still not sure why a specific initial condition is needed in the IVP

if we pick $\lambda $ to be negative as time goes to infinity all entries go to 1 for some reason

Comment: Perhaps only $x_{0} and y_{0}$ need to be 0?

Comment: @Faust7: Nope. I edited :)